# How to detect new line in result of ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get result of **PartialViewResult** in asp.net mvc project via ajax.When Model is null ! I pass nothing in partialViewResult but I get newline in result of ajax.How can i detect it by js?

[image]

```
 var GetSuns = function (btn) {
            $('body').append('<div class="WrapProgress"><img  class="loadingimg vertical-middle-image" src="/Content/Travelo/images/travelenter_process_Art.gif" /></div>');
            var urn = $(btn).data('urn');
            var method = $(btn).data('method');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/art/ShowTime',
                data: { s: urn, method: method },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.trim) {
                        console.log("1"+result+"1")
                        $('.WrapProgress').remove();
                        $('#ModalSuns .modal-body').html(result);
                        $('#ModalSuns').modal('show');
                    } else {
                        $('#Modal').modal('show');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStates, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    $('.WrapProgress').remove();
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Just FYI, if `result` is a string you need to use `if(result.trim())` - note the `()`

Comment: ok it solved ..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  is correct here

Comment: trim is a function use it as trim()

Comment: If it's solved please accept an answer or add a note to your question noting the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is anyway the `result.trim` need to changed to `result.trim()` inorder to `trim` the result string for any trailing spaces or linebreaks.

In order to detect line breaks in your code

```js
text = `


`;
numberOfLineBreaks = (text.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
console.log(numberOfLineBreaks)
```